# SQL Server Query to Display Rows that is 8 Days Before and 8 Days after the Scheduled Due Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

As stated in my title, is it possible to display my table rows which falls to the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 1
WHERE DueDate is less than 8 days and greater than 8 days to current date
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [BETWEEN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) expression.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN GetDate() - 8 AND GetDate() + 8
```

Also, if you require eliminating the time component, you can do something like:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
SELECT @CurrentDate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT )) AS DATETIME)

SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN @CurrentDate - 8 AND @CurrentDate + 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(dd, 8, GETDATE())
```